# Custom thumbnail on SlideJS plugin

Tags: slidesjs

Is there a way to make the thumbnail images different from the fullsize images on a gallery using SlideJS plugin?

OUR SOLUTION:

We also didn't found anything on the documentation and solved it the following way:

1. Create a custom attribute on the HTML of the thumbnails gallery:

   ```
   <div id="thumbnails">
       <img src="/path/to/thumbnail.jpg" fullsize="/path/to/fullsize.jpg" />
       <img src="/path/to/thumbnail.jpg" fullsize="/path/to/fullsize.jpg" />
       <img src="/path/to/thumbnail.jpg" fullsize="/path/to/fullsize.jpg" />
       [...]
   </div>

   <div id="slideshow"></div>
   ```
2. When some thumbnail gets clicked, make a copy of the thumbnails div HTML, switch the attribute values and set the slideshow:

   ```
   $('#thumbnails img').click(function() {

       // Get a copy of element instance of thumbnails div
       var thumbnails = $(this).parent();

       // On that copy, switch "img" attribute with "fullsize" attribute of each image
       // and remove "fullsize" attribute for cleanliness
       thumbnails.children('img').each(function() {

           $(this).children().first().attr('src', $(this).children().first().attr('fullsize'));
           $(this).children().first().removeAttr('fullsize');

       });

       // Set the switched HTML to the div that will hold the slideshow
       $('#slideshow').html(thumbnails.html());

       // Set the slideshow
       $('#slideshow').slides({
           start: 1,
           preload: true,
           generateNextPrev: true,
           generatePagination: false,
           effect: 'fade'
       });

   });
   ```

Comment: ... I've searched in the documentaction and Google and found nothing.

Comment: are you looking fr this https://kopepasah.com/tutorial/easily-add-custom-thumbnail-pagination-to-slidesjs/